# How to do something on table when it is fully loaded with data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function on table load event i.e whenever table is fully loaded with data.

```
       $("#student_info_tbl").load(function(){
             libraryupdates();
        });

        function libraryupdates()
        {

            $('#student_info_tbl tbody tr').each(function(j) {
            });
        }
```

How to call this function when table is completely loaded with data.
Note that libraryupdates(); function hides something from table.

Comment: What is loading the data into the table?

Comment: What does "fully loaded" means to you" ? If nothing is altering your table, wrapping your code in a `$(function(){ ... })` will wait for your page to fully load.

Comment: An ajax function is loading data in the table

Comment: put the `libraryupdates()` in `Ajax sucess:` attr.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your function in the "success" callback of your ajax request.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    // Fill table with data 
    libraryupdates()
  })
```

Comment: I've supposed example.php is the endpoint for retrieving data to fill the table, so "Fill table with data" is a placeholder for a method that renders results in table, AFTER that, you can call the function. Maybe I've misunderstood ?

Comment: Yeah, I may have been too fast on that one. Anyway I did a rollback on my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a responsible answer. But you can try this.

```
$.when($('#student_info_tbl').ajax(some data or parameters)).then(libraryupdates());
```